# How to recursively call a function for a set period of time?

Tags: java

I would like to recursively call the run() function when my IOException is caught if and only if the total execution time for this method has been <= 10 seconds. I mistyped the google.com link purposely so that the IOException always gets thrown and caught but it seems like the run(); method isn't being successfully recursively called. What did I do wrong here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Thread() {           
      
    public void run() {                                    
        Document doc;                                      
        try {                                              
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.comt/").get();
          
            runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                     // do stuff
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {                          
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            if (System.nanoTime() <= 10000000000L) {    // 10 seconds
               run();                                   // RECURSIVE CALL
             }
           }
         }
       }.start
     }
```

Comment: this is supposed to be always false actually: `System.nanoTime() <= 10000000000L`

Comment: Oh why is that? And do you know of a better way of doing this?

Comment: Note: it is a bad idea to use recursion here. Remember: every method call creates another stack frame. When you use recursion, those stack frames start stacking up (because a method needs to **end** before its stack frame can be dropped). Thus: **never** use recursion when you have no clue how many times your method will be called. You risk indeterministic stackoverflow exceptions otherwise. Of course, here you might only have a few recursions, but still. One way to think about this: command objects that perform specific actions.

Comment: Command actions can go into queues, and a command might decide ... to simply add itself to such a queue, in case it needs to be "repeated".

Comment: @Kevin you are checking if less than 10 seconds have passed since January 1st, 1970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= 10000){
  run();
}
```

If you want use nano seconds, you can try as below:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(System.nanoTime() - startTime <= 10000000000){
      run();
    }
```

Comment: @Dora why do you ever need `while` here?

Comment: @mangusta To recursively call the run() method for 10 secs.

Comment: @Dora what do you mean by "for 10 secs"? The author clearly stated that `run` should be called if the total execution time is less than 10 secs

Comment: Use `nanoTime()` whether you want the precision or not. It's more likely to monotonically increase. No matter what you can see jumps backward and forward, but they are more likely with `currentTimeMillis()`. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308031939/https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) has more info.